# .htaccess URL rewrite (break single entity into two)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Have tried several suggestions from this site, Google searching, and other sources to no avail.

I would like to have a re-write rule that takes a url like this:

```
http://somesite.com/abc123
```

and changes it to this:

```
http://somesite.com/abc/123
```

abc123 is a dynamic set but will always be comprised of (alpha)(numeric) - b256, d1, c3456, etc.

Is there any way to do this with .htaccess?  Everything I'm trying just isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done.. quite easily actually assuming that you are always going to split across the alphas and the numbers.... your .htaccess would say:

```
Rewrite on
RewriteRule ^([A-z]+)([0-9]+)(.*)   $1/$2$3             [QSA,L]
```

Note that QSA appends any query strings and L stops the rule here. The rest is for good measure... in case there is something like /abc123.html then it would become /abc/123.html

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this myself a while back. The .htaccess doesn't need to create it, it just needs to handle it. I hope Im right with this :)

This will handle the it in the .htaccess

```
Rewrite on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)([^/]*)$ index.php?varone=$1&vartwo=$2 [L]
```

But you will need to have it linked on your page this way

```
http://somesite.com/abc/123
```

Then you can request the vars with php

```
    $varone = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["varone"]);
    $varone = preg_replace("/[^A-z]/","", $varone);


    $vartwo = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["vartwo"]);
    $vartwo = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $vartwo);
```